# How do you delete the ?ReturnToUrl query string on log out?

Tags: c#, asp.net, login-control

I have this in my LoginControl.ascx code behind:

```
protected void Logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon();
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    Response.End;
    //Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
}
```

I expected that on logout the user would be redirected to the login page (default.aspx in this case) and there would be *NO* query string attached.  Instead, what I see on the URL is:

```
http://kab.domain.com/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAdministration%2fCharacter%2fView.aspx
```

So now, after logging out, I want to log in as another person (with lesser privileges) and on a successful login it redirects me to a page that this new login does not have permissions to see!  <grrr />

*I realize that the "normal" user will never run into this issue but the test users do and it is a bug as far as they are concerned.*

Even with the Response.Redirect I still get the query string.  How do I get rid of the query string at logout???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
```

Comment: I added a full URL and now it is redirecting without a query string.

Response.Redirect(RivWorks.AppSettings.RootUrl + "default.aspx");

Comment: Looks to be the same when you get down to brass tacks.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void signout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Response.Write("<script language=javascript>var wnd=window.open('','newWin','height=1,width=1,left=900,top=700,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,maximize=false,resizable=1');</script>");
      Response.Write("<script language=javascript>wnd.close();</script>");
      Response.Write("<script language=javascript>window.open('login.aspx','_parent',replace=true);</script>");
      Session["name"] = null;
    }
}
```

---

I'm also adding on all page this code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
      Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
    }
}
```